# Weather Forecast Web Service

Tags: asp.net

I want to understand more how to get third party web services working, after looking through tutorials I have managed to get a QuoteOfTheDay(); web service working. But I do not know where to start with this one:

http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/WeatherForecastService.svc?wsdl

Any tips in the right direction would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Service Reference (right click on you project in Solution Explorer and select Add service reference). In url field input "http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/WeatherForecastService.svc" and click OK. Master will generate a proxy class to this WCF service.

Then you can use this WCF service as any other web service.

As you can see in wsdl, this service provide two methods - GetCitiesByCountry and GetForecastByCity. I think it is obvious what they do.

I don't see any documentation for this WCF service. I only found small sample for Java. It invokes GetCitiesByCountry method:
http://doc.nuxeo.com/display/NXDOC/Building+a+SOAP-based+WebService+client+in+Nuxeo